# Populate the summary count for all status values

Tags: java, java-8, enums, java-stream

I have an `Enum` as follows for all the statuses:

```
enum Status {    
    ACCEPTED("Accepted"),
    REJECTED("Rejected"),
    FAILED("Failed");

    private final String label;

    Status(final String label) {
        this.label = label;
    }
}
```

A model to map the results of the query I run from the database:

```
public class Summary {    
    private LocalDate date;
    private Status status;
    private int count;    
}
```

Say my database returns the following excluding any counts for `Rejected` for 24th & `Failed` for 27th:

```
DATE        | status        | count
20-01-24    | Accepted      | 1     
20-01-24    | Failed        | 40        
20-01-27    | Accepted      | 10        
20-01-27    | Rejected      | 15
```

How can I still include the summaries for `rejected` & `failed` for those dates along with the above?

I call the db as follows:

```
final List<Summary> statuses = this.dbRepo.getSummaries(someCriteria);
```

but this list does not include the `Rejected` & `Failed` as they are not returned by the DB.

Through Java 8 and stream operation, is there a way to check all available enum values for `Status` and where there is one status missing in `statuses` for the dates, include it with a count of 0?

What I have so far and tried is get the results from DB and put these into a Map as follows:

```
public Map<LocalDate, List<Summary>> getSummaries(final SomeCriteria someCriteria) {
    return this.namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(this.QUERY,
            new MapSqlParameterSource()
                    .addValue("date", someCriteria.getFrom())
            ((rs, rowNum) -> Summary.builder()
                                                    .date(rs.getDate("date").toLocalDate())
                                                    .status(valueOfLabel(rs.getString("status")))
                                                    .count(rs.getInt("count"))
                                                    .build())
    ).stream().collect(groupingBy(Summary::getDate));
}
```

Comment: Any SQL you could show us?

Comment: Apart from that it should be corrected as `Rejected for 27th & Failed for 24th`. Also please show us what you have tried so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use nested `grouping` to create the initial lookup `Map`

```
Map<LocalDate, Map<Status, Summary>> lookup = statuses.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Summary::getDate,
                Collectors.toMap(Summary::getStatus, Function.identity())));
```

and then perform the remaining task while iterating all `Status` values for each date such as:

```
List<Summary> overallResult = lookup.entrySet().stream()
        .flatMap(en -> EnumSet.allOf(Status.class).stream()
                .map(status -> en.getValue().containsKey(status) ?
                        en.getValue().get(status) : Summary.builder()
                                .date(en.getKey()).status(status).count(0).build()))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

With the input provided in the question this would result in:

> ```
> Summary(date=2020-01-27, status=ACCEPTED, count=10)
> Summary(date=2020-01-27, status=REJECTED, count=15)
> Summary(date=2020-01-27, status=FAILED, count=0)
> Summary(date=2020-01-24, status=ACCEPTED, count=1)
> Summary(date=2020-01-24, status=REJECTED, count=0)
> Summary(date=2020-01-24, status=FAILED, count=40)
> ```

Answer (score 0):

This is something I'd do in two steps, in a poor man's version of a cartesian self-join (on the pre-grouped data):

```
//select status, date, sum(count) group by status, date
Map<Status, Map<LocalDate, Integer>> existingCounts = 
    summaries.stream()
    .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(
        Summary::getStatus, 
        Collectors.groupingBy(Summary::getDate, 
                              Collectors.summingInt(Summary::getCount))));

List<Summary> result = Arrays.stream(Status.values())
    .flatMap(
        status -> existingCounts.values()
                   .stream().distinct()
                   .flatMap(
                           map -> map.keySet().stream()
                                    .map(date -> new SimpleEntry<>(status, date))))
    .map(e -> new Summary(e.getValue(), e.getKey(),
        existingCounts.containsKey(e.getKey())
                ? (existingCounts.get(e.getKey()).containsKey(e.getValue())
                        ? existingCounts.get(e.getKey()).get(e.getValue()).intValue()
                        : 0)
                : 0))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

The above produces this list:

```
[date=2020-01-27, status=ACCEPTED, count=10]
[date=2020-01-24, status=ACCEPTED, count=1]
[date=2020-01-27, status=ACCEPTED, count=10]
[date=2020-01-24, status=ACCEPTED, count=1]
[date=2020-01-27, status=REJECTED, count=15]
[date=2020-01-24, status=REJECTED, count=0]
[date=2020-01-27, status=REJECTED, count=15]
[date=2020-01-24, status=REJECTED, count=0]
[date=2020-01-27, status=FAILED, count=0]
[date=2020-01-24, status=FAILED, count=40]
[date=2020-01-27, status=FAILED, count=0]
[date=2020-01-24, status=FAILED, count=40]
```

Answer (score 0):

Doing this in single step maybe would be possible but I think it wont be so readable! 
and doing it in several stepp make it clear IMO!

in first step: group by *date* and *status* properties.

```
Map<LocalDate, Set<Status>> groupByDateAndStatus = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Summary::getDate,
               Collectors.mapping(Summary::getStatus, Collectors.toSet())));
```

> {2020-01-27=[ACCEPTED, REJECTED], 2020-01-24=[FAILED, ACCEPTED]}

in second step group summary with *date* and available *status*.

```
 Map<LocalDate, List<Summary>> map = list.stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(Summary::getDate,
                summary -> new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(summary)), YOURCLASS::merge));
```

and in last step add `summary` for absent `status`.

```
EnumSet.allOf(Status.class)
        .forEach(status -> groupByDateAndStatus.entrySet()
        .stream()
        .filter(entry -> !entry.getValue().contains(status))
        .forEach(entry -> map.merge(entry.getKey(), 
 new ArrayList<Summary>(Collections.singletonList(new Summary(entry.getKey(), status, 0))),
                                                                           YOURCLASS::merge)));
```

and merge method:

```
private static List<Summary> merge(List<Summary> l1, List<Summary> l2) {
   l1.addAll(l2);
   return l1; 
}
```

output:

```
{
  2020-01-27=[
      Summary{date=2020-01-27, status=ACCEPTED, count=10}, 
      Summary{date=2020-01-27, status=REJECTED, count=15}, 
      Summary{date=2020-01-27, status=FAILED, count=0}], 
  2020-01-24=[ 
      Summary{date=2020-01-24, status=ACCEPTED, count=1}, 
      Summary{date=2020-01-24, status=FAILED, count=40}, 
      Summary{date=2020-01-24, status=REJECTED, count=0}
    ]
}
```

---

```
Map<LocalDate, List<Summary>> map = new HashMap<>();
Map<LocalDate, Map<Status, Summary>> lookup = list.stream()
        .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Summary::getDate,
            Collectors.toMap(Summary::getStatus, Function.identity())));

EnumSet.allOf(Status.class)
        .forEach(status -> lookup
            .forEach((key, value) ->
               map.merge(key, new ArrayList<>(Collections.singletonList(value.getOrDefault(status, new Summary(key, status, 0)))),
                                    YOURCLASS::merge)));
```